# Cambiar el formado de fecha de un datepicker ( "/" por un "-") para pasarlo por URL el Valor

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Tengo una pagina donde te dirige a un enlace personalizado SEGUN la fecha que seleccionas, el problema es necesitaba evitar que se seleccionaran SABADOS Y DOMINGOS (Lo hice) con un `datepicker` y en el `input` en vez de poner `input date` puse `input text` (para que funcione el `datepicker`).

El problema que tengo ahora es que en vez de ponerme por ejemplo: `02-09-2022` me pone `02/09/2022` y obviamente no me funciona el enlace porque los `/` son separadores... Necesito una forma de reemplazar los `/` por los `-` para que se setteen en el link.. dejo el codigo abajo para que entiendan.

HTML

```html
<input type='text' class="form-control" id="fecha" />
```

Boton donde tengo que imprimir el parametro fecha:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm-lg" id="btn-guardar"><a href="http://PAGINAXYZ/XYZ/XYZ/{fecha}" style="color:white" target="_blank" id="link">
```

javascript usado

```javascript
$(function() {
   $('#fecha').datepicker({
       $.datepicker.appendText: "(mm-dd-yyyy)",
       beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends

   });
});
```

**¿Como puedo modificar el formato para que me lo imprima en el link?**

Comment: como el sistema sabe que ```{fecha}``` tiene un valor?, por alli puedes empezar y formatear la fecha

Comment: ok para poder ayudarte necesitamos saver la version de jquery y de datepicker que usas ya que hay como 6-7 librerias que se llaman datepicker por ejemplo dinos de donde la descargaste ... todo esto debe estar en tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El formato en el plugin `datepicker` se establece en la inicialización del plugin con la propiedad/parámetro `dateFormat`.

Ejemplo:

```javascript
$(function() {
    $('#fecha').datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends 
    });
});
```

[Documentación.](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat)

**Nota:** estoy casi seguro que en la mayoría de los plugins se utiliza la misma propiedad; si alguien encuentra alguna diferencia, favor actualizar esta respuesta.

Comment: Excelente, al rato de hacer la pregunta pude hacerlo exactamente como me lo indicas! Muchisimas gracias por tu aporte, seguro le servirá a alguien mas en un futuro jeje

Comment: en realidad Jquery esta en dehuso... al igual que los plugin

Comment: Como en deshuso?? No entiendo

Comment: me refiero a que JQuery esta siendo abandonado poco a poco... en pro de usar javascript vanilla... segun los nuevos estandares ES6 y ES7 ...

Comment: en mi empresa tienen toneladas de archivos con jquery... Hay que cambiar todo entonces? o sea, en su momento... Soy junior por eso aun no comprendo bien eso de dejar de usar o usar otra cosa...

Comment: en su momento les va a tocar; pero por ejemplo Bootstrap 5 ya no lo usa ... y asi hay varios plugin y librerias que estan dejando de usar jquery.